EvtSubscribe not returning signal when using pull subscription
I used the same code given in [Microsoft documentation] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wes/subscribing-to-events#pull-subscriptions) to collect logs in real-time by subscribing to the event source "Application" in the event viewer but when the logs flow rate is high/log collection prolongs continuously for longer duration say 1-2days the waitForMultipleObjects function stop returning the signal.To simulate logs from PowerShell the following command was used and the EvtSubscribe query param were as follows
For($x=1; $x -lt 2000000; $x=$x+1)
{
   Write-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "MyApps" -EventID 1116 -EntryType Error -Message    "MyApp." -Category 1 -RawData 10,20
}

pwsPath = L"Application"
pwsQuery = "*"
EvtSubscribe(NULL, aWaitHandles[1], pwsPath, pwsQuery, NULL, NULL, NULL,EvtSubscribeStartAtOldestRecord);

From the a above Powershell command the log collection from the application runs for around 10minutes and stops abruptly and the event xmls are not printed in command prompt\console application
Tried with push subscription - for reference , and it works as intended and the log collection doesn't stop with high flow/log duration of time
What am i doing wrong here? Kindly help

I can reproduce the issue and just start the document code to collect the Application channel. I submit new internal feedback. It seems you have to use the push model now.

Hi Yang! Thanks for your reply , So is this a Microsoft issue and they have decided to deprecate the pull subscription model?

NO. I just report it with the new internal feedback.
